# What makes this still a "beta"?

Tags: discussion

I am fairly new here to Physical Fitness stack exchange. I was just wondering what makes this a beta site compared to the other stack exchange sites?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obsolete.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Fitness has completed the mid level graduation process and is no longer a beta site.

Answer (score 0):

It is still in the process of becoming a "full" stack exchange site.

Here are the FAQ's for Area51, where new/proposed sites get their start.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq